# php html input inside label

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to print the output of the php script inside input tags in html but it doesnt work. I've tried "**htmlentities**" and "**htmlspecialcharacters**" but still not printing anything. But if i type anything inside input tags it shows up fine. How can i use php inside  tags?

```
<label class="control-label" id="temp">
            <input type="hidden">
                        <?php echo 'helo'; ?>
            </input>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show up because the input is hidden. Change `<input type="hidden">` to `<input type="text">`

Comment: Also, `input` is not used in the way OP tries to use it, it does not have a closing tag. There is no `<input>xy</input>`, only `<input value="xy">`.

Comment: Yes it has the closing input tag

Comment: i cant use type="text" because i dont want it editable. I want to use it as label. I've tried label but people prefer to use input tags with type hidden instead of using label with php.

Comment: if you dont wan't it to be editable just add readonly to the input tag. This way the user can't edit it. Also keep the type='text'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value=''`

```
$x =  'Hello';
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$x'";
```

So in your case:

```
<label class="control-label" id="temp">
            <input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo 'helo';?> "> 
</label>
```

I haven't tested this though but I believe you can do that in this way.

Comment: i forgot to put in the question that i have tried that also and it doesnt work.

Comment: @rutulpatel Run these lines of codes `$x =  'Hello'; echo "<input type='text' value='$x'";` in http://writecodeonline.com/php/ - and you can see it running.